# AWS Amplify: How can I update temporary password (NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED) with completeNewPassword?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redux, amazon-cognito, redux-saga, aws-amplify

**Issue:**

How can I update a user's temporary password (`NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED`) with `completeNewPassword`?

[I've looked through the docs and I can't find anything on updating the temporary password.](https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/api/classes/authclass.html#completenewpassword)

**Steps:**

1. Create user in AWS Amplify
2. A text is sent with a temporary password
3. The user should go to `www.website.com/update-temporary-password`
4. Where does the user enter in the temporary password/Which method (completeNewPassword?) do I use?

**updateTemporaryPasswordSaga.js:**

```
// Redux Saga: Update Temporary Password
function* updateTemporaryPasswordSaga(action) {
  try {
    // Credentials
    const { temporaryPassword, newPassword, newPasswordConfirm } = action.credentials;

    // AWS: Update Temporary Password
    yield call([Auth, 'completeNewPassword'], temporaryPassword, newPassword, newPasswordConfirm);

    // Redux: Update Temporary Password Success
    yield put(updateTemporaryPasswordSuccess());

    // React Router: Account
    yield action.history.push('/account');
  }
  catch (error) {
    // Redux: Update Temporary Password Error
    yield put(updateTemporaryPasswordError(error));
  }
};
```

**Temporary Password Text:**

[image]

Comment: I'm not quite understanding your question. Could you clarify?

Comment: Yea, I’m having the user trying to login with a temporary password. The account status NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED. How can I have the user login with the temporary password and/or have the user update that temporary password to their desired password?

Comment: So you need to route front end to a page which requires users enter new password. And then on that page you collect new password and call the function completeNewPassword from Amplify in this case

Comment: You can try the Hosted UI from Cognito to see the entire flow

Answer (score 1):

I hope this answers your question. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/1340) thread. As I understand it the user first needs to sign in with the temporary password and afterwards you use the ***completeNewPassword*** function to change the temporary password.

Comment: Perfect!! I was trying to use the Auth.changePassword method, but that method requires the user to be signed in. Cheers Mircea.